# Typescript child has same props as parent, is there a cleaner way to do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Quiz question component prop types :

```
type Props = {

    question_details: question_details,
    handle_back_click: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
    handle_next_click: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
    question_number:number

}
```

It renders a child component QuestionButtons like so

```
   <QuestionButtons

        answer_selected={answer_selected}
        handle_back_click={handle_back_click}
        handle_next_click={(e)=> handle_next(e)}
        question_number={question_number}

    />
```

Which also has the same props

```
type Props = {

    answer_selected: string,
    handle_back_click: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
    handle_next_click: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
    question_number:number

}
```

My question is, is there a cleaner way to do this, so I do not repeat the props, without using redux or moving the QuestionButtons component into the parent quiz question component

Answer (score 0):

You can pass rest props:

```
   <QuestionButtons
        answer_selected={answer_selected}
        {...props}
    />
```

which `props` is those that are same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` operator to do it.

```js
<QuestionButtons
  answer_selected={an swer_selected}
  { ...questionProps }
/>
```